# A question on finite $p$-groups.

Tags: finite-groups, p-groups

Is true that if $G$ is a $p$-group finite, say, $\mid G \mid = p^d$, then $G$ is $d$-generated?

Comment: If is true, then into which book to find a demonstration of this fact?

Comment: This was answered in your previous question.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: I think this question is a useful lemma in understanding the (comments for Derek's answer to the) original question, and that it stands on its own logically as well. It might still be a duplicate, but surely not of Agenor's previous question!

Comment: @yatima2975 The question itself isn't a duplicate, but the reference he requests was *literally* just given to him in another answer.

Comment: @AlexanderGruber: He didn't get the book reference he asked for! The question askers first language is not English, and judging from his other questions his group theory is shaky as well. My instinct would be to spell it out in painful detail (while preventing real duplicates): what's obvious to Derek Holt might not be obvious to you, what's obvious to you might not be obvious to me, and what's obvious to me might not be obvious to Agenor.

Comment: @yatima2975 I'd agree with you, but he *did* receive the book reference, from Boris Novikov (who later deleted his answer for some reason after interacting with OP) citing the exact theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If $d$ generated means "generated by d elements", much more is true: If the Frattini quotient $G/\phi(G)$ has order $p^n$, then $G$ is generated by n elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because it is $k$-generated, where $p^k$ is the order of $G/\phi(G)$, where $\phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $G$.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frattini_subgroup and [https://www.math.colostate.edu/~clayton/courses/602/602_4.pdf](https://www.math.colostate.edu/%7Eclayton/courses/602/602_4.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Something stronger is true: if $|G| = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \ldots p_n^{e_n}$, then there is a generating set for $G$ of size $\sum_{i=1}^n{e_n}$. The bound is sharp (at least) for products of elementary $p$-groups.

I don't have a reference at hand, but it's easy to prove. The idea is that if you have a set $X$ such that $\langle X \rangle \neq G$, you can find an element $y \in G - \langle X \rangle$. Since $\langle X \cup \{ y\} \rangle \neq \langle X \rangle$, the size will increase by at least one prime factor: $| \langle X \cup \{ y\} \rangle : \langle X \rangle | \gt 1$. Therefore, starting with the empty set, you'll find a generating set for $G$ in a number of steps that's at most equal to the sum of the exponents in the prime factorisation of $|G|$.

This latter number is called the multiprimality of $|G|$, see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeFactor.html or the delightful paper ["Counting groups: gnus, moas and other exotica"](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/%7Eobrien/research/gnu.pdf) by Conway et al.